# a stop job is running for make remote cups printers available locally

Tags: services, cups

At almost each shutdown of my Linux Mint 18.2 Cinnamon 64-bit, I must wait ages at:

> a stop job is running for make remote cups printers available locally

Some information I find most useful:

1. I have one installed local USB printer unattached unless I need it.
2. That said, I don't have an idea what the system is waiting for.
3. The printer is HP, so HPLIP has been installed.
4. I repeat, that at shutdown, the printer is never attached to the USB.
5. But typically once a week I need to print on it.
6. May I disable the cups-browsed service to solve this?

I mean:

```
sudo systemctl disable cups-browsed.service
```

And the printer would still work?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

At first glance on [its Ubuntu man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/cups-browsed.8.html):

> **cups-browsed**  -  A daemon for browsing the Bonjour broadcasts of shared, remote CUPS printers.

it is safe to assume disabling it will not affect printer connected locally.

---

It turns out, that the printer functionality is not damaged by disabling the cups-browsed service:

```
sudo systemctl stop cups-browsed.service
sudo systemctl disable cups-browsed.service
```

So, no longer endless waiting for the computer to reboot!